# 3d integral, python, integration set constrained

Tags: python, math, scipy, calculus

I wanted to compute the volume of the intersect of a sphere and infinite cylinder at some distance b, and i figured i would do it using a quick and dirty python script. My requirements are a <1s computation with >3 significant digits.

My thinking was as such: 
We place the sphere, with radius R, such that its center is at the origin, and we place the cylinder, with radius R', such that its axis is spanned in z from (b,0,0). We integrate over the sphere, using a step function that returns 1 if we are inside the cylinder, and 0 if not, thus integrating 1 over the set constrained by being inside both sphere and cylinder, i.e. the intersect.

I tried this using scipy.intigrate.tplquad. It did not work out. I think its because of the discontinuity of the step function as i get warnings such the following. Of course, i might just be doing this wrong. Assuming i have not made some stupid mistake, I could attempt to formulate the ranges of the intersect, thus removing the need for the step function, but i figured i might try and get some feedback first. Can anyone spot any mistake, or point towards some simple solution.

> Warning: The maximum number of
>   subdivisions (50) has been achieved.
>   If increasing the limit yields no
>   improvement it is advised to analyze
>   the integrand in order to determine
>   the difficulties.  If the position of
>   a    local difficulty can be
>   determined (singularity,
>   discontinuity) one will    probably
>   gain from splitting up the interval
>   and calling the integrator    on the
>   subranges.  Perhaps a special-purpose
>   integrator should be used.

Code:

```
from scipy.integrate import tplquad
from math import sqrt


def integrand(z, y, x):
    if Rprim >= (x - b)**2 + y**2:
        return 1.
    else:
        return 0.

def integral():
    return tplquad(integrand, -R, R, 
                   lambda x: -sqrt(R**2 - x**2),          # lower y
                   lambda x: sqrt(R**2 - x**2),           # upper y
                   lambda x,y: -sqrt(R**2 - x**2 - y**2), # lower z
                   lambda x,y: sqrt(R**2 - x**2 - y**2), # upper z
                   epsabs=1.e-01, epsrel=1.e-01
                   )

R=1
Rprim=1
b=0.5
print integral()
```

Comment: Can you try setting b=0, R=Rprim=1 first? In this case your step function is always 1 (the sphere is completely inside the cylinder), thus the result should come out just equal to 4\pi/3.

Comment: Yea, but i want a solution for any b, R and R'.

Comment: I'd argue it's a general strategy: any time a complicated thing doesn't work, the first shot at debugging it is to consider a simplified case.

Comment: Yes, I need to read stuff more then once. Because if i don't, i make an ass of myself.

 While it might be helpful for debugging, the consensus seems to be that the problem with my attempt at a solution relies on integration over a discontinuous function using a integrator that cant handle such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using a simple MC integration, as suggested by eat, but my implementation was to slow. My requirements had increased. I therefore reformulated the problem mathematically, as suggested by woodchips.

Basically i formulated the limits of x as a function of z and y, and y as a function of z. Then i, in essence, integrated f(z,y,z)=1 over the intersection, using the limits. I did this because of the speed increase, allowing me to plot volume vs b, and because it allows me to integrate more complex functions with relative minor modification.

I include my code in case anyone is interested.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from math import sqrt
from math import pi

def x_max(y,r):
    return sqrt(r**2-y**2)

def x_min(y,r):
    return max(-sqrt(r**2 - y**2), -sqrt(R**2 - y**2) + b) 

def y_max(r):
    if (R<b and b-R<r) or (R>b and b-R>r):
        return sqrt( R**2 - (R**2-r**2+b**2)**2/(4.*b**2) )
    elif r+R<b:
        return 0.
    else: #r+b<R
        return r

def z_max():
    if R>b:
        return R
    else:
        return sqrt(2.*b*R - b**2) 

def delta_x(y, r):
    return  x_max(y,r) - x_min(y,r)

def int_xy(z):
    r = sqrt(R**2 - z**2)
    return quad(delta_x, 0., y_max(r), args=(r))

def int_xyz():
    return quad(lambda z: int_xy(z)[0], 0., z_max())

R=1.
Rprim=1.
b=0.5
print 4*int_xyz()[0]
```

Comment: Glad to see that you'll be able to find out a better solution :). Unfortunately I can't see how you could really generalize this approach to "more complex functions" (whatever they may be). Anyway "analytical" solutions are superior when they are computable really reliable manner. But they seldom are :(. FWIW, stochastic methods can be fine tuned far beyond my simple demonstration (both in accuracy and execution performance), but what IMHO counts is that such methods tends to be very robust ones when handling "real world" data. Thanks

Comment: I already did. The cylinder represents a incoming sphere/ion in a nuclear collision. I used the implementation as above to calculate the volume directly affected by the collision. Next I needed to calculate the integral of the flux of incoming nucleus represented by the cylinder. To do this i replaced delta_x with a integral of a function, flux, over x. and defined flux as sqrt(R**2-x**2-z**2). After some normalization, I had calculated what i wanted, assuming no mistakes. I rarely do this sort of stuff, Its part of a course I'm taking. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are able to translate and scale your data such a way that the origin of the sphere is in `[0, 0, 0]` and its radius is `1`, then a simple stochastic approximation may give you a reasonable answer fast enough. So, something along the lines could be a good starting point:

```
import numpy as np

def in_sphere(p, r= 1.):
    return np.sqrt((p** 2).sum(0))<= r

def in_cylinder(p, c, r= 1.):
    m= np.mean(c, 1)[:, None]
    pm= p- m
    d= np.diff(c- m)
    d= d/ np.sqrt(d** 2).sum()
    pp= np.dot(np.dot(d, d.T), pm)
    return np.sqrt(((pp- pm)** 2).sum(0))<= r

def in_sac(p, c, r_c):
    return np.logical_and(in_sphere(p), in_cylinder(p, c, r_c))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n, c= 1e6, [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
    p= 2* np.random.rand(3, n)- 2
    print (in_sac(p, c, 1).sum()/ n)* 2** 3
```

Comment: +1. This. Quick & dirty Monte-Carlo integration is much faster to set up and much less error prone (and probably more efficient) than trying to integrate a 3D function with no regularity by discretization. And above all, it scales better: accuracy is sqrt(N), for what you want to achieve, it is likely N^(1/3). An improvement may be to use quasi-random numbers (eg. Sobol sequences).

Comment: MC integration, obviously. my brain must be off today. Thanks.

Comment: @qonf: No, your brain is not off today, I found myself continuously in the situation where I'm trying to find out of a nice analytical solution. But many times numerical (and especially stochastic) solutions are actually good enough ones. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Performing a triple adaptive numerical integrations on a discontinuous function that is constant over two domains is a terribly poor idea, especially if you wish to see either speed or accuracy.

I would suggest a far better idea is to reduce the problem analytically.

Align the cylinder with an axis, by transformation. This translates the sphere to some point that is not at the origin.

Now, find the limits of intersection of the sphere with the cylinder along that axis.

Integrate over that axis variable. The area of intersection at any fixed value along the axis is simply the area of intersection of two circles, which in turn is simply computable using trigonometry and a little effort.

In the end, you will have an exact result, with almost no computation time needed.

Comment: IIRC there exists a clever change of variable for intersection of a ball (not a sphere btw!) and a cylinder.

Comment: Ops, I re-read your your comment, and i misrepresented it in my previous comments, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First off: You can calculate the volume of the intersection by hand. If you don't want to (or can't) do that, here's an alternative:

I'd generate a tetrahedral mesh for the domain and then add up the cell volumes. An example with [pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh/) and [meshplex](https://github.com/nschloe/meshplex/) (both authored by myself):

```py
import pygalmesh
import meshplex
import numpy

ball = pygalmesh.Ball([0, 0, 0], 1.0)
cyl = pygalmesh.Cylinder(-1, 1, 0.7, 0.1)
u = pygalmesh.Intersection([ball, cyl])

mesh = pygalmesh.generate_mesh(u, cell_size=0.05, edge_size=0.1)

points = mesh.points
cells = mesh.cells["tetra"]

# kick out unused vertices
uvertices, uidx = numpy.unique(cells, return_inverse=True)
cells = uidx.reshape(cells.shape)
points = points[uvertices]

mp = meshplex.MeshTetra(points, cells)
print(sum(mp.cell_volumes))
```

This gives you

[image]

and prints `2.6567890958740463` as volume. Decrease cell or edge sizes for higher precision.